# What should be Blog page URL if we think regarding SEO friendly

Tags: seo, url, blog

I am going to integrate BLOG to my website. Which is best SEO friendly URL for blog from below :

1 - blog.mysite.com

2 - mysite.com/blog

Please advice me so I can do as per that. I am SEO beginner and want to make everything perfect because My blog will have fresh posts daily , weekly and want to generate traffic by blog.